# Can smoke have collision with an object created using the array modifier?

Tags: modifiers, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, collision

I have some objects created using the array modifier that I'd like to act as collision objects in a smoke simulation. I know that I could apply the modifier to make the object instances real, but is there a way to make smoke have a collision array with the modifier-generated objects directly?

[image: Original Object, smoke simulation collision works]

[image: Array Object, smoke simulation collision fails]

@TheJeran pointed out that the modifier order was important, but this doesn't seem to work for me either.

[image: Array Object, with fluid simulation above array fails]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup!

Just swap the order so that Array comes first in the modifier stack

[image]

Comment: It seems like that should work, but it isn't working for me. I'll add a third image to the question.

Comment: @DanaWilliams Sometimes cache is stacked ... just change Domain division resolution +/-1 to get it fresh.

Comment: Thanks, TheJeran, and @vklidu. I had the modifiers in the wrong order and I wasn't clearing the cache correctly.